# Can't Get SQL to pull Correct DateTime

Tags: t-sql, ssms

So I am running into an issue and for the life of me i can't figure out how to get the data I am looking for.

What I am trying to do is get a collection of data between a certain Date/Time, the way the database was set up the date and time is in different columns and the way its formatted is yyyyMMDD for the date and hhmmss for the time. (Not sure if this would matter but i just want to make sure i explain everything) The Data is located in an old DB2 server, I am using a linked server in SSMS to pull the data over. The part of the query I am having trouble with is

```
SELECT *
FROM WM370BASD.PRTRAN00   A 
WHERE
(
       A.PRTXTP            =     '300'                         
AND    A.PRTXCD            =     '003'                         
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210901  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     060000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     140000    --END TIME                  
)
OR
(      A.PRTXTP            =     '200'                         
AND    A.PRTXCD            =     '001'                         
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210901  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     060000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     140000    --END TIME                                      
AND    A.PRMNOP            =     'Dir Putaway'
)   
OR     
(      A.PRTXTP            =     '200'                         
AND    A.PRTXCD            =     '001'                         
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210901  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     060000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     140000    --END TIME  
AND    A.PRMNOP            =     'Locate Cases'                
)
OR     
(      A.PRTXTP            =     '200'                         
AND    A.PRTXCD            =     '001'                         
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210901  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     060000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     140000    --END TIME                 
AND    A.PRMNOP            =     'SKU Putaway'                 
)
OR     
(      A.PRTXTP            =     '200'                         
AND    A.PRTXCD            =     '002'                         
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210901  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     060000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     140000    --END TIME                                    
AND    A.PRMNOP            =     'Pull Cases-Bulk'   
)
```

**EDIT** --Added result set

```
 PREDTI PREDDT
 60001  20210901
 60005  20210901
 60010  20210901
 60012  20210901
 60012  20210901
 60013  20210901
 60024  20210901
 60025  20210901
 60032  20210901
 60042  20210901
 135950 20210901
 135947 20210901
 135938 20210901
 135937 20210901
 135934 20210901
 135928 20210901
 135923 20210901
 135923 20210901
 135921 20210901
 135918 20210901
```

It works fine as long as the day is the same day, However if I would span it across a day, it returns nothing....

```
AND    A.PREDDT           >=     20210821  --BEGIN DATE
AND    A.PREDDT           <=     20210901  --END DATE    
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     140000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     030000    --END TIME
```

I figure whatever the issue is is small and stupid and i am just overlooking it, i would appreciate a fresh set of eyes!

Comment: Will you ever have a range of dates, i.e. begin date not equal to end date? If so, you'll need to handle checking the begin date/time pair separately from the end date/time pair to ensure the correct results.

Comment: Yes, whoever created the old Database Created them as integers, so its not technically a date 2021/09/01 its an integer 20210901 so technically im getting a range between two integers.

Comment: My point was that if you have _different_ dates in the range, e.g. 3 May 1997 through 17 June 1998, then you need to handle the dates separately. The start time only applies on 3 May 1997. Any time on 4 May 1997 through 16 June 1998 is within the range, as is _part_ of 17 June 1998 until the End Time. That your chosen representation of time might be number of base cycle Garlic Croutons after local sunrise as a string of Unicode Roman numerals is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following condition will ALWAYS be false because a number cannot be less than 30000 and greater than 140000 at the same time.

```
AND    A.PREDTI           >=     140000    --BEGIN TIME 
AND    A.PREDTI           <=     030000    --END TIME
```

Making it as follows:

```
AND (    A.PREDTI           >=     140000    --BEGIN TIME 
OR    A.PREDTI           <=     030000    )  --END TIME
```

Using parenthesis because AND takes precedence over OR and using OR instead of AND. Now it should return results sometimes, but without understanding your logic or intent, I can't say if it is correct or not.

I recommend using DateTime type instead of integers as it is created specifically for that purpose.
You would run into other issues if you use integers the way you do.

Edit:
If I understand what you want correctly, you want from 21/8 to 1/9 and the time be between 14:00 and 3:00 (the next day).
So on 21/8 the time must be after 14:00
On 22/8 to 1/9 the time must be before 3:00 or after 14:00
On 2/9 (next day) the time must be before 3:00

This can be expressed with the following expression:

```
AND (
   A.PREDDT >= 20210822 AND A.PREDDT <= 20210901      
   AND (A.PREDTI >= 140000 OR A.PREDTI <= 030000)
   OR A.PREDDT = 20210902 AND A.PREDTI <= 030000
   OR A.PREDDT = 20210821 AND A.PREDTI >= 140000
)
```

Comment: If i would of built the original Table I 100% would of used DateTime, however its an old system I inherited and i am unable to move it/update it. so sadly i am stuck with using integers. I also tried converting the integers to DATETIME to pull the information, however it takes my query from a minute or two run, to about a 13 minutes run, Old database with around 75 million records...I am trying to create a report that pulls data only between certain times. from the example above i would want to pull the data between 09/01/2021 at 6am to 09/01/2021 at 2pm. what Breaks is when i try to pull...

Comment: Something over night, so if i try to get the data between 08/31/2021 at 2pm to 09/01/2021 at 3am. My query works for pulling data on the same day, just when i combine multiple days and does not always return false. For example if i would run the query that pulls data from the same day, it would return some results like

Comment: I added **Result set** Above for formating, but you can some data that would be return

Comment: I updated the answer based on my understanding of your requirements.